# Have I messed up by saying "thank you, see you on the 25th" in response to an email giving me a Zoom link for an interview?

Tags: interviewing, communication, job-search

I’m panicking slightly. I have an interview coming up and it will be on Zoom. The employer sent me a link and said here’s the Zoom link, see you soon.
I replied “thank you, see you on the 25th”

My partner said my response was cold so I'm now worried. I have already sent them a video of myself which I felt I came across bubbly but I am worried I have messed up. Or am I over thinking it?

Comment: Tag this question worrying-about-nothing.

Comment: If the interview is on the 25th, your response is fine, I certainly wouldn't be bothered by it if I received it from a candidate.

Comment: Not many stackoverflow questions make me laugh out loud at the workplace! Hope you feel less worried soon Jessie.

Comment: You ruined all of your chances for the job :D In reality, they likely do not spend half of second thinking about candidates responses other than yes or no.  ;)

Answer (score 9):

> Have I messed up?

Not really. A response like

> *“thank you, see you on the 25th”*

to an interview invite is fine. However, if you want to sound a little more formal, you can also write

> *“Thank you. Looking forward to seeing you on the 25th.”*

Answer (score 7):

If the 25th is in fact the date of your interview, you have done nothing wrong.  In fact, the thing you may have done wrong was sending the video after the fact; asking someone to watch a video to make you appear bubbly is kind of a big ask, and companies don't usually have time to watch video responses to emails (and asking them to do so it kind of out of the ordinary anyway and makes you look "eccentric", in a bad way).

In future, if you want to not appear cold, you can put a smiley-face on your response, like instead of "see you on the 25th", you could say "see you on the 25th :)".  That would be sufficient, in my opinion.

Comment: Please try not to use smiley face as a substitute for words. How about "Looking forward to seeing you on the 25th"? "I'm excited to be interviewing with you"?

Comment: Agree the video is odd and doesn't jive with common workplace practices - most companies would actively discourage employees from opening unsolicited, unexpected attachments from individuals outside the company because of security issues.

Comment: Hi thanks for your feedback. The video was something the recruiter asked me to prepare as a first stage interview. It was sent a couple of weeks ago and as a result I have a face to face interview. 

I think I was just worried I hadn’t said “I look forward to meeting you on the 25th…”

Comment: I would use the "I am looking forward to meeting you on the 25th." but my feeling is they are primarily looking for evidence that an actual human received the zoom link - so a simple "RCVD" would probably suffice.  Sometimes these things end up in the SPAM folder or for other reasons not seen.

Comment: @emory What does RCVD stand for ?

Comment: @Itération122442 it is shorthand for "RECEIVED" - acknowledging that you have received a message.

Answer (score 3):

> I have an interview coming up and it will be on zoom. The employer sent me a link and said here’s the zoom link, see you soon. I replied “thank you, see you on the 25th

When they send the invite, is it a calendar invite or did someone send an email pasting the link? I ask because if it is a calendar invite, all you have to do is click Accept and show up on the time.

As far as replying, if they sent it in an informal way like you said, then replying in such a fashion is okay. You're basically confirming you got the email and that you understood it will be on the 25th.

That's it. On the 25th, just be there on the zoom call and you're okay.

Comment: It was an email with a pasted link. 
I think I’m probably over thinking it. Thanks for replying.